# rxjs observable stream: how to perform a side effect on every nth event?

Tags: rxjs6

I want to perform a side effect after every 20 emits on an interval stream that continues indefinitely. Is it possible to perform a do/take side effect after n emits on a repeating cycle with an rxjs observable stream?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the windowCount

Just simple as this:

```
Observable
    .of(...)
    .windowCount(20)
    .switchMap(val => val.takeLast(1))
    .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```